# Why does my Ubuntu system make the sound of a loud bell ringing every day at a certain time? How can I debug where this is coming from?

Tags: sound

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

I was just sitting with my headphones on after watching a video and suddenly heard the sound of a bell ringing 3 or 5 times very loudly (like the kind of bell you might hear at a pier). Since then I've notice that this actually appears to happen every day at the same time; no idea how long this has been going on as I don't normally have my headphone on at that time (only started doing it as a way to check that this bell ringing is happening more than that first day I heard it).

It sounds just like this (except it rings 5x instead of just 3x): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvvTacquttk

What could this be? I don't think it had anything to do with YouTube or any of my key presses. I can't recreate it.

Programs open at the time were: Chrome, ClamTK, Terminal, Text Editor, Document Viewer. None of them seemed to have started or ended any processes that I might then associate with this sound. Nothing was showing in my notifications history when clicking the date at the top of my desktop screen.

Trying some random stuff and looking at log info, this is what I could see (though I don't think any of this is related):

```
➜  ~ journalctl --since "1 hour ago" | grep -iE "error|warning|bell|notification"
Nov 21 10:36:45 gnome-shell[3483]: Warning: disabling flag --expose_wasm due to conflicting flags 
Nov 21 11:00:33 gnome-shell[3483]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

When I go to Settings > Sound, I see that Alert Sound is set to Default (which does not sound like a bell), but System Sounds is set to mute, so I don't think that's it either.

Why does my Ubuntu system make the sound of a loud bell ringing every day at a certain time? How can I debug where this is coming from?

Will try to see if it's related to an open tab in Chrome (exiting chrome before 11AM and seeing if it still happens).

*UPDATE: Played every `.wav` file on my system to listen for the sound using the command...

```bash
find "/" -type f -name "*.wav" 2>/dev/null | while read -r wav_file; do aplay "$wav_file"; done
```

... and keeping ready to hit `ctl+c` when I heard the sound to pinpoint it, but never heard it (only had a few `.wav` files on my system, so I would not have just missed it somehow).

*UPDATE: Per the user comments, ran this command around the time of the sound...

```bash
watch -n0.5 'pacmd list-sink-inputs | tee -a sound-inputs.log'
```

... and found that the sound was coming from Google Chrome. Not sure what to do about this information now (as I have many dozens of tabs open on the affected computer and the logged application process ID only points to the generic Chrome "Utility: Audio Service" process), but hoping to do something like as described here (https://superuser.com/questions/488070/how-can-i-find-out-which-tab-sound-is-coming-from). (If @Rinzwind would like to post their comment as an Answer, I'll approve it, else leaving this question up (despite turning out to not be Ubuntu-related) since it has some instructive information that can be useful in generalized situations).

Comment: Does this happen often? Can you record the sound and include it in your question?

Comment: @Raffles Yes, every day at 11AM since the time I started tracking it. I will try to record it, good idea.

Comment: @Raffles OK, I found a video with the same sound that I'm hearing from my system. Added it to the question.

Comment: Firstly try doing a full search for all .wav files and see if you can identify one that sounds like what you are hearing, I know this will be tedious because I just looked on my machine and there are thousands. Could it possibly be a format other than .wav? If you can identify such a file, its folder might give you a clue. Also, you are running Clam antivirus, is it not set to do something at that time?

Comment: What sound system are you using? 20.04 should be pulseaudio so .... `pactl list clients`  lists all connected programs and `watch -n0.5 'pacmd list-sink-inputs | tee -a sound-inputs.log'`   will catch the event.   Or is it pipewire? Or alsa?